# After khulla when can a woman marry someone else?

Tags: women, talaq

Aoa,i have filed for khulla,my reconcilation time is over...i ave not yet recieved an official khulla notice from the court.My question is when can i marry someone else.How long would be the iddat period?

Comment: No it is not duplicate, it is different. Talaq and khula are different.

Answer (score 1):

*All Perfect Praise be to Allah.*

With regard to the ‘iddah following khula’, the correct scholarly view is that it is one menstrual cycle, as is indicated by the Sunnah.

> It was narrated from Ibn ‘Abbaas that the wife of Thaabit ibn Qays
>   ended her marriage to her husband by means of khula’ at the time of
>   the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him). The Prophet
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) commanded her to observe
>   an ‘iddah of one menstrual cycle. (Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 1185; Abu
>   Dawood, 2229. Also narrated by al-Nasaa’i (3497) from the hadeeth of
>   al-Rabee’ bint ‘Afra’. The two hadeeth were both classed as saheeh by
>   Ibn al-Qayyim).

So, you should wait **1 month as iddah period after khula**(as of sharai point of view.), and **be aware of all judicial procedures of your country to avoid any complexities before re-marriage**.
And this waiting period of 1 month will only start when court has declared the khula. Notice is not the condition here, declaration of khula is.

Allah knows best.